# Is there any collection of PowerShell scripts that help the task of SQL Server maintenance?

Tags: sql-server, management, powershell, scripting

I've been studying PowerShell and I've been (slowly) getting it into my day-to-day DBA tasks.

So far I've seen a bunch of disconnected PowerShell scripts for many disparate administration activities.

What I'd like to know is if there is an official (or recognizable) PowerShell scripts collection or repository that people usually go to for SQL Server PowerShell scripts for common DBA activities (something like Ola Hallengren's T-SQL scripts).

Comment: Good question.  I imagine there is a non-definitive list somewhere.  If there's something you need to do in PS for DBA Admin, you can ask here as well I think.

Comment: I've listed some resources and eBooks (not scripts per se, but definitely things that can help you write and understand them) toward the bottom of this post: https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/26/useful-free-resources-for-sql-server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know that anyone has written something along the lines of Ola's script within PowerShell. I know that PowerShell scripts for SQL Server are slowly growing over at the [TechnNet Script Center](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=databases&f%5B0%5D.Text=Databases&f%5B1%5D.Type=SubCategory&f%5B1%5D.Value=sqlserver&f%5B1%5D.Text=SQL%20Server&f%5B2%5D.Type=Tag&f%5B2%5D.Value=Powershell&f%5B2%5D.Text=Powershell). Then [MSSQLTips.com](http://www.mssqltips.com/sql-server-tip-category/81/powershell/) also has started publishing tips working with SQL Server and PowerShell.

Then you also have [SQL Server PowerShell Extenstions](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/) project over on CodePlex. I don't guess you would consider it a repository but a good number of folks blog on how to use it and such. Some task within SQL Server are made much easier using SQLPSX.

I also tend to check out a few MVP blog sites that tend to focus on PowerShell scripts:
[Allen White](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/allen_white/archive/tags/PowerShell/default.aspx)
[Aaron Nelson](http://sqlvariant.com/wordpress/index.php/tag/powershell/)
[Sean McCown (MidnightDBA)](http://midnightdba.itbookworm.com/Admin.aspx) (Click on the PowerShell tab for all the videos on the subject)

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of scripts on codeplex for database administration; I believe @sqlvariant has had a hand in writing them

Comment: Are you referring to something different on Codeplex from Shawn when he said: "Then you also have SQL Server PowerShell Extenstions project over on CodePlex"?