# How to automatically execute a stored procedure every day at a particular time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express, scheduled-tasks

Can you please help me how to execute a stored procedure automatically in SQL database without any transaction in SQL? I want to execute on particular fix time.

Comment: What database system are you using? SQL Server (Microsoft), MySQL, other? Please [edit] your question to add a tag for that. Also, what have you tried so far, what did you find in your research and why didn't that work?

Comment: It's a **stored** procedure - a procedure **stored** inside your database system. It has nothing to do with a "store" per se ...

Comment: how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8688446/2186023 and then just let task scheduler take control of that...

Comment: And you can not execute anything in SQL without a transaction. ANYTHING is in a transaction - explicit or implicit.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4079363/164901 -- I recently implemented the Service Broker solution for one of our projects here, and I can tell you that it's not exactly newbie-friendly. It is a great solution, though.

Answer (score 8):

If you are not comfortable using Powershell, then you can go for native service broker functionality.

- This might sound complex, but below links has all the scripts :

  [Scheduling Jobs in SQL Server Express - Part 1](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express) and

  [Scheduling Jobs in SQL Server Express - Part 2](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express-2)
- Alternatively, you can use [Standalone SQL Agent - still in BETA statge](http://standalonesqlagent.codeplex.com/) from codeplex.
- You can use the **native sqlcmd** functionality and then schedule it using [windows scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

  ```
  sqlcmd -E -S server_name -d database_name -Q "EXEC schema_name.StoredProcedureName @p1"
  ```

Answer (score 6):

With SQL Server Express, you could use powershell to execute a stored procedure automatically through Windows scheduler service.

There is a great article that shows how to use Powershell to EXEC stored procedures here:

http://www.maxtblog.com/2010/10/basic-sql-server-stored-procedure-scripting-with-powershell/

You can also look at this question that deals with using Powershell:

[Is there any collection of PowerShell scripts that help the task of SQL Server maintenance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13043/is-there-any-collection-of-powershell-scripts-that-help-the-task-of-sql-server-m)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by "without any transaction". But normally timed scripts / tasks are executed as jobs, through the SQL Server Agent. See here for an example and explanation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216272/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-in-a-sql-agent-job

Comment: @Khan SQL Agent is not available in Express edition.

Comment: Ah, tags. Good point. :)

Answer (score -1):

The answer to the question "How to make a stored procedure automatic with execution parameters" in Sql server is simple, we will only have to go to the **SQL server Agent, "New" -> "Job" ->** we will use three tabs **"General"," Steps","Schedules"** in **"General"** we will only give it a name, **"Steps"** ->**"New"** and here we will have to add the **execute of the stored procedure**, **"Schedules"** we make the execution time parameters and save, I hope this is of help to someone, greetings

Comment: The question is tagged "SQL Express" which does not have SQL Agent as an option.

Comment: It also sounds like its from chatgpt.

Comment: La pregunta esta etiquetada como "Como ejecutar **automáticamente**  un procedimiento almacenado"  por eso específico para aquellos que buscan una solución en SQL server --Saludos